# Ballerina Lang Package Build Failed

Tags: ballerina

This issue raised when following the [Ballerina Community Programme](https://ballerina.io/community-program/) I tried to create **calculator** package and till build everthing nicely worked.

When execute **ballerina build calculator** command , below error pops at the terminal.

```
ballerina: Oh no, something really went wrong. Bad. Sad.

There should be a file named "ballerina-internal.log" in the current directory.

If you are able to share with us the code that broke Ballerina then
we would REALLY appreciate if you would report this to us:
go to https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues and
create a bug report with both this log file and the sample code.

We thank you for helping make us better dancers.
```

And the ballerina-internal.log reports this.

```
    [2018-07-10 11:41:19,518] ERROR {org.ballerinalang.launcher.Main} - Illegal character in opaque part at index 34: jar:file:/home/nadeeshan/Ballerina Projects/CalculatorBallerina/.ballerina/repo/nadeeshan/calculator/0.0.1/calculator.zip 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 34: jar:file:/home/nadeeshan/Ballerina Projects/CalculatorBallerina/.ballerina/repo/nadeeshan/calculator/0.0.1/calculator.zip
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
    at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.FileSystemProjectDirectory.saveCompiledPackage(FileSystemProjectDirectory.java:165)
    at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.BinaryFileWriter.writeLibraryPackage(BinaryFileWriter.java:153)
    at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.BinaryFileWriter.writeLibraryPackage(BinaryFileWriter.java:125)
    at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.BinaryFileWriter.write(BinaryFileWriter.java:89)
    at org.wso2.ballerinalang.compiler.Compiler.build(Compiler.java:96)
    at org.ballerinalang.packerina.BuilderUtils.compileAndWrite(BuilderUtils.java:54)
    at org.ballerinalang.packerina.cmd.BuildCommand.execute(BuildCommand.java:94)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.ballerinalang.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 34: jar:file:/home/nadeeshan/Ballerina Projects/CalculatorBallerina/.ballerina/repo/nadeeshan/calculator/0.0.1/calculator.zip
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ballerina package build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153910/ballerina-package-build-failed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate question [Ballerina package build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153910/ballerina-package-build-failed)
As answered in the previous question, it might be due to the space in the project directory `Ballerina Projects`. Try renaming it to `Ballerina-Projects`.